# iPhone Action Sheet Cancel Button Only Responds to Touch Near Center

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I have encountered something like this before, where a button only responds to touches in part of its view. I found a image view with a transparent area was on a higher z-level, which obscured the touches where the overlap occurred. This was due to the button being added as a subview before the obscuring view was added.

In the case of an action sheet, I thought it would be at the highest z-level over anything else. Since the action sheet was just initialized and shown, there is no way that I can see that something is covering the button.

(For what it's worth, I just converted the app into a universal app, and am testing in both iOS 4.3 and 5.0. There is no cancel button in the action sheet on the iPad. This problem exists when simulating for iPhone for both iOS 4.3 and 5.0.)

I'm looking for other ideas as to what is causing the problem.

UPDATE
Here is the code to show the action sheet

```
- (void) shareButtonPressed {

    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem larkspreeSearchResult:searchResult];
    item.image = eventImageRaw;

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    // Display the action sheet
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}
```

Since this is for a subclassed action sheet, this, right out of ShareKit, might be helpful, too.

```
+ (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type
{
SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share")
                                                      delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
as.item.shareType = type;

as.sharers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
NSArray *favoriteSharers = [SHK favoriteSharersForType:type];

// Add buttons for each favorite sharer
id class;
for(NSString *sharerId in favoriteSharers)
{
    class = NSClassFromString(sharerId);
    if ([class canShare])
    {
        [as addButtonWithTitle: [class sharerTitle] ];
        [as.sharers addObject:sharerId];
    }
}

// Add More button
[as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"More...")];

// Add Cancel button
[as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Cancel")];
as.cancelButtonIndex = as.numberOfButtons -1;

return [as autorelease];
}
```

The showInView method has not been overridden.

Comment: Please paste the code from the view controller in question. Specifically where you send `-showInView:` to the action sheet.

Comment: I updated with some of the code. Please let me know if more would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a bottom bar of some sort? If this view controller is part of a `UINavigationController` with a toolbar configured or a `UITabBarController` then any action sheet needs to be presented in the parent controller's view. For instance, `[actionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.view];` or `[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];`.

Comment: I'll give you credit for the answer if you write it up. It was not quite what you said. My view is inside a tabBarController. However, there is no self.tabBarController, so I tried `[actionSheet showInView:self.view.superview];` and that worked. Then I tried `[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];`, putting it in the Window, and that worked. I don't see this requirement in the documentation, though. Can you point it out?

Comment: You should really start thinking about using `UIViewController` to manage views that you're adding into `UITabBarController`. You're missing out on a lot of free functionality by directly manipulating the view hierarchy.

Comment: I just realized that the view that is showing is a subview of Window (this is intentional) and not of the tabBarController (which is the rootViewController), so that is why the tabBarController reference didn't work. I still don't see where it says in the documentation that my action sheet has to be added to that level of the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

If this view controller is part of a `UINavigationController` with a toolbar configured or a `UITabBarController` then any action sheet needs to be presented in the parent controller's view. For instance, `[actionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.view];` or `[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];`.